# selecting asp.net adjacent text boxes using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I want to select an adjacent asp.net textbox which is inside a table cell using css class attribute.

The html is as below:

```
<td colspan="">
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
          ControlToValidate="txt_zipcode" SetFocusOnError="true"  
          ErrorMessage="Zip Code" Display="None" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtbox zipcode" Width="40px" ID="txt_zipcode" 
          runat="server" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
</td>
<td class="txtcaption" align="right">
    City:
</td>  
<td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txt_city" CssClass="txtbox city" MaxLength="30" Width="120px"
          runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

The jquery code is as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.zipcode').next('input:text').hasClass('city');
});
```

The above code always return false value. I am trying to select City textbox which is below the zip code text box. Do you have solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

next will search within siblings and the next input element is in next table cell which is not a sibling. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($('.zipcode').parent().siblings().find('input:text').hasClass("city"))
});
```